# Removing rotors from 2007 Honda accord

Tags: honda

How can I remove the front passenger side rotor of my 2007 Honda Accord if I stripped the rotor screw ? I’ve already tried using the “Grab it” to back it out and that didn’t work.  Now it looks like the screw has bonded with the rotor . Can I just drill a hole through it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you provide an image of which "screw" you stripped? It would make it a lot easier to give you advice about it.

Comment: Do mean the rotor retainer screw, ie the screw that holds the rotor on the spindle? And do you mean you stripped the head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the bolt that attaches the rotor to the hub then it is not essential. Just drill it out.

Its only there to make putting the wheel on easier so you don't have to try to line up the wheel bolt threads through the rotor and wheel.

You can of course drill and tap it to make a proper job of it but to get your job done for now there is no problem with just drilling the head of the bolt off.